# Snowflake external table partition include the field name and value

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, partition, external-tables

In the S3 storage, the partition is stored in the format "partition_mon_yr=202203." Upon ingestion by Glue, Glue interprets "partition_mon_yr" as the field name and "202203" as its corresponding value. This discrepancy arises because Snowflake external files construct the partition field from the metadata field value, resulting in a combined representation like "partition_mon_yr=202203."

Is it a good idea to extract the substring and store the "202203" value in the partition_mon_yr column in Snowflake? so that if the same data is used in Glue and Snowflake both will display in the same way.  But my question arises, If I store whether partitioning against S3 will work or snowflake partitioning on an external table will not work with S3.

```
In Snowflake 
Actual partition value

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE et1(
  partition_mon_yr string AS SPLIT_PART(metadata$filename, '/', 3)
  col1 varchar AS (value:col1::varchar)  
  col2 varchar AS (value:col2::varchar))
  PARTITION BY (partition_mon_yr)
  LOCATION=@s1/logs/
  AUTO_REFRESH = true
  FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = PARQUET);

partition_mon_yr contains the value partition_mon_yr=202203

Extract the YYYYMO value:

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE et1(
  partition_mon_yr string AS SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(metadata$filename, '/', 3),'=',2),
  col1 varchar AS (value:col1::varchar)  
  col2 varchar AS (value:col2::varchar))
  PARTITION BY (partition_mon_yr)
  LOCATION=@s1/logs/
  AUTO_REFRESH = true
  FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = PARQUET);

partition_mon_yr contains the value 202203.
```

Comment: Hi - I’m not sure I understand your question. A Snowflake external table definition logically describes how to display the underlying data, it’s not partitioning anything. Therefore it’s not clear why you think how you define an external table in Snowflake has any impact on S3?